# Can this wall support books on track shelving?

Tags: walls, studs, shelving, load

I would like to install a track shelving system on a wall to hold books, and want to ensure that the setup could hold the load safely (and also not destroy the wall). I’ve found mixed info* and am looking for guidance.

General questions:

- How much weight can a stud bear?
- What is the best way to attach weight to a stud (presumably a screw, but how many and in what arrangement)?

Specific questions:

- Would my planned setup be able to support the expected weight of many books?
- Is this a bad idea and should I just use a bookshelf (or possibly go for a built in)? In terms of space use, wall shelves are optimal, but safety is my main concern as we have a small child.

Details:

- [Example/inspiration image](https://i.imgur.com/WDBWjrL.jpg)
- The wall is ~59” wide. Studs are placed as marked off by the tape in this picture.[image: Wall with blue tape showing stud locations]
- The shelves would be 12” deep, 3/4” thick plywood spanning the length of the wall.
- I would use either three or five [standards screwed into the studs](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Rubbermaid-70-in-L-White-Standard-Support-Bracket-Shelf-Track-FG4B8900WHT/100047070) OR a [top rail system](https://www.containerstore.com/s/elfa/predesigned-spaces/living-spaces/elfa-d%C3%A9cor-4%27-white-and-birch-basic-shelving-units-for-anywhere/123d?p=0&ps=62&productId=11012513) where only the rail goes into studs and the standards are not load bearing (depending on advice given)
- Ultimately, the goal would be to have six shelves, but we might start with four.
- A generous estimate for the book weight is 20–30 lbs per linear foot. So four fully-loaded shelves would be 400–590 lbs, six would be 590–885 lbs in the max scenario.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

**Various things I’ve found: anywhere from 100–500 lbs per stud; and/or, 100 lbs per screw; but also that, even if you use multiple screws, it’s the top screw that will bear most of the force, so it’s the only relevant one; and, at some point putting too many screws into studs starts to weaken them.*

Comment: The top rail system makes lining things up a lot easier. You can also drop odd uprights as needed if you want to vary the lengths of some shelves. The rails from [freedomrail](https://shop.organizedliving.com/freedomrailrails-uprights/) are rated at up to 150 pounds per linear foot, i.e. across width of the wall. Just a happy customer.

Comment: I think the answer is: it depends what the manufacturer of the track system says.

Comment: To be sure, I'd follow the guidelines on whatever hardware was used (the freedomRail example being *up to* 750 lbs for a 5 foot span, which is within range for my purposes). But is there never a situation where the wall/stud strength becomes the limiting factor, and the heavy-duty brackets with their fully-loaded shelves take down the wall before they themselves fail? This is also a load-bearing wall afaik. I'm now leaning away from this solution due to the answer below, but just wanted to clarify my initial reason for concern.

Comment: If you install a rail at the top of the wall you may be able to attach it to the top plate with screws much closer together than using several studs. Note that some rail/upright combinations may require clearance above the rail to allow you to hook the uprights on.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the style of support. A triangular bracket (e.g., [these](https://www.findthisbest.com/best-shelf-brackets/triangle)) distributes weight from the outside end of the shelf to the wall, and the longer the hypotenuse, the better the distribution. (If mounted *above* the shelf, a bracket could also serve as book-end.)

Vertical [standards and brackets](https://www.thespruce.com/installing-wall-shelves-with-standards-1398290) might not hold as much, but if you put a standard at every stud, it *might* be enough. However, because shelves often *rest* on those brackets, rather than being screwed in place, eventually, slight warping of a shelf could cause most of the load to be borne by just a few brackets. <sub>*thud*</sub>

Comment: Thanks—I considered triangular brackets, but is it an issue that there’d then be many more screws along a single stud? Ex: 4 shelves with each bracket attaching to the stud at two points is 8 good size holes, whereas the standard tracks would attach at just 3 or 4 points. 6 shelves would be 12 holes.

With the track shelving, I had planned to screw the shelves in to the brackets (there’s typically a hole at the bottom of the brackets to drill up through) though it’s true this may be more to stabilize than to securely attach them. Maybe I could use a thicker shelf to prevent warping?

Comment: If each standard only has 3 or 4 screw holes, I'd have less faith in their staying attached. BTW, consider book-cases, or at least adding one board at each end down to the floor, to have the *floor* take up some of that weight. Also, do not make deep shelves, as cantilevering out from the wall adds strain.

Comment: @catbirdsofa I think the issue with too many screws per stud is more when you have lots of screws close together. I don't think adding additional screws on a triangular bracket below the shelf would compromise the stud.